# Is there a GPU system monitor for Debian?

Tags: nvidia, software-rec, gpu

I use a system monitor to watch CPU, memory and network usage on my Debian 8:
[image: A common system monitor]

I need a GPU (graphic) monitor. I tried differentes monitors with and without GIU but they don't show GPU.

Why the system monitors don't watch GPU? Is there any alternative option for any Linux distro?

Comment: I take it from the tags you’re after a GPU monitor for NVIDIA GPUs. I don’t know about anything for NVIDIA; for AMD GPUs there’s [`radeontool`](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/radeontool) (I don’t know how well it works), for Intel GPUs there’s `intel_gpu_top` in [`intel-gpu-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/intel-gpu-tools) which works well.

Comment: nvidia-smi does some monitor for some cards.